# Can't remove fuel line connector from fuel pump

Tags: fuel-system, volvo, fuel-pump

I am trying to replace the fuel pump of my Volvo V70 I 2.4 (106kW, 1998, manual), but can't remove the fuel line connector from the pump assembly. The return line seperated easily, but the other one won't budge.

[image: Fuel pump connector]

I've pulled down the lower sleeve towards the pump and then tugged it upwards, which worked perfectly for the other one. This one is thoroughly stuck. I've already tried to apply some WD40, without success. I've also tried to pull it out with pliers with as much force as I dared, but to no avail.

How can I remove it?

Comment: I should mention I've depressurized the fuel system using the schrader valve on the injector rail if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you twist it enough to break the bond?

Comment: Yes, it rotates freely. Can't twist it a lot though, because the line is pretty short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a diagram that shows a special tool to remove the fuel lines from the top of the pump assembly.

[image: Volvo fuel line tool]

It says "Move the outer sleeve of the coupling upward. Avoid pinching the sleeve"
If you look at the tool shown, I believe you could find something similar or make a tool that would do the same thing without much trouble. To me, it looks like you need to put an even amount of upward pressure on the outside part of the connector but at least 1/3 of the way around.

Comment: Finally got it off. Here's a little follow-up:
For some reason the releasing mechanism was stuck properly. After trying to pry it off with different tools and from different angles, I decided to cut off the rubber sleeve and see what's going on. From there the releasing mechanism as clearly visible and made it easy to depress it. It was still on very tightly, and required a lot of persuasion to come off, but ultimately it worked. Quick visual inspection shows that the connector is intact on the inside and should be reusable. Both O-Rings are still intact.